# HttpURLConnection to download file from Servlet not working, direct link works

Tags: java, servlets, pdf, httpurlconnection

Have a list of 8,000+ HTTP links to PDF files to download. Reading in each link and calling my method downloadFile() and saving it to local Window$ PC. Coming across 2 link formats:

http://example.com/docs/pdfs/Downloadable.pdf

http://example.com/docs/download.do?AttchmentId=2000

The first type (direct) always works. The second one does not work. When it saves the file as a pdf, it looks like:

```
<div id="error">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
<form id="download" name="download" method="post" action="/careManager/DownloadFormController.do?AttachmentId=2000">
<input type="hidden" name="attachID" value="2000" >  
</form>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
 document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
</body>
</div>
```

When I follow the non-working links in my browser's developer tools, it is getting redirected to a HTTPS site (changing the protocol to HTTPS) by javascript files.

What am I missing?

I have tried setting the cookiehandler, setting the system property http.strictPostRedirect to true, setting the connections setFollowRedirects and setInstanceFollowRedirects to true, creating a new URL connection if forwarded/moved, setting the connection setReadTimeout, creating a HttpsURLConnection for SSL.  All have not worked for the servlet.

```
public static void downloadFile(String downloadUrl, String fileName) throws Exception {

    CookieHandler.setDefault( new CookieManager( null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL ) );
    // String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie( downloadUrl.toString() );
    URL url  = new URL( downloadUrl );
    File file = new File( "C:\\temp\\smc1\\" + fileName );

    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    System.setProperty("http.strictPostRedirect", "true");

    int responseCode = c.getResponseCode();
    InputStream is;

    if( responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
            || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
            || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER ) {

        // Get new URL (https) from HttpURLConnection frowarding
        URL newUrl = new URL( c.getHeaderField("Location") );
        HttpURLConnection sc = (HttpURLConnection) newUrl.openConnection();

        sc.setFollowRedirects(true);
        sc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        responseCode = sc.getResponseCode();
        // sc.setReadTimeout(15*1000);

        is = sc.getInputStream();
    } else {
        c.setFollowRedirects(true);
        c.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        responseCode = c.getResponseCode();
        is = c.getInputStream();
    }
    // System.out.println( " Code: " + responseCode );

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( file );

    int bytesRead;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[ 1024 ];
    while( ( bytesRead = is.read(buffer) ) != -1 ) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    if( fos != null ) {
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
    if( is != null ) {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

I am a consumer of the servlet and only have the link as access.
Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by:

1. editing the default download location of my default browser
2. develop loop to launch browser with url and download each file in default location

My default browser is chrome. I also watched how many tabs were opened to automatically close the browser and launch a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This will *never* work, no matter how much extra code you write that does what Java already does by default when redirecting.

The HTML page auto-posts a form that causes a download when loaded by a browser. Java code will never execute that.

Comment: Yes. But it looks Like one can parse the resulting HTML and forge a HTTP post request that is equivalent to what à browser would do. Might be worth a try.

Comment: @ EJP - any ideas on how to accomplish?  

@GPI - can you provide a link so I can learn how to do that?  

Thanks!

Comment: @GPI Of course you can. The browser does it. But it isn't built-in to Java.